# Using JSON instead of GeoJSON in Leaflet with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, leaflet

I'm looking for a way to use JSON instead of GeoJSON in leaflet using AJAX. Using JSON and AJAX are required.

I managed to call JSON file using AJAX. However, now I'm confused how I can use data in JSON to plot markers on map. I'm guessing I can't use L.geoJson().

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
```

This is the JavaScript file:

```
var map;
var overlay;

var addPopupsFromLocations = function(locations) {
  var popups = new Array();
  locations.forEach(function(location){
    console.log('creating popup for location ' + location.title);

    console.log(location.latitude);
    console.log(location.longitude);
      }) ;
};

function init() {
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3'
        }).addTo(map);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
    $.ajax('locations.json', {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: addPopupsFromLocations,
        error: function(xhr, st, et) {
          console.warn(et);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Weathertop",
    "link": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weathertop",
    "latitude": 51.505,
    "longitude": -0.09,
    "imageUrl": "assets/img/location-images/Weathertop.jpg"
  },
{
  "title": "Rivendell",
  "link": "http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rivendell",
  "latitude": -0.09,
  "longitude": 51.505,
  "imageUrl": "assets/img/location-images/Rivendell2.jpg"
},
{
  "title": "Minas Tirith",
  "link": "http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Minas_Tirith",
  "latitude": 38.78,
  "longitude": -77.18,
  "imageUrl": "assets/img/location-images/320px-Minas_Tirith.jpg"
}

]
```

Console:

```
creating popup for location Weathertop
custom.js (line 7)
51.505
custom.js (line 9)
-0.09
custom.js (line 10)
creating popup for location Rivendell
custom.js (line 7)
-0.09
custom.js (line 9)
51.505
custom.js (line 10)
creating popup for location Minas Tirith
custom.js (line 7)
38.78
custom.js (line 9)
-77.18
```

Answer (score 5):

> I'm looking for a way to use JSON instead of GeoJSON in leaflet using AJAX.

Okay: to review some terms,

- JSON is a basic data-interchange format. It doesn't contain anything in particular.
- GeoJSON is a subset of JSON that is formatted to be map-friendly and understandable to things like Leaflet.

If you want to use L.geoJson, you need to reformat your data so that it fits the [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html). You can do this with basic JavaScript.

```
var geojsonFormattedLocations = locations.map(function(location) {
    return {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [location.longitude, location.latitude]
        },
        properties: {
            location
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a late answer but you definitely can use simple JSON format with Leaflet.

As you say, you receive the JSON with ajax and on success, you run a function that loops each JSON object and for each one, adds a marker on the map. For example:

```
var response = req.responseText;
var arr = JSON.parse(response);

for (var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
    L.marker([arr[i].latitude, arr[i].longitude]).addTo(map);
}
```